# OBSOLETE - StackFlair Widget - Highly customizable user flair widget for Android

Tags: app, obsolete, android, widget

[image: Logo]

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

### About

StackFlair is a highly customizable widget which displays your profile information (flair) from any website that is part of the Stack Exchange Network (http://stackexchange.com/).

★★ Key features ★★

> ✓ Supports all 100 StackExchange sites
>
> ✓ Fully customizable widget appearance - colors, text alignment,
> badges, ...
>
> ✓ Two resizable** widgets (with and without profile picture)
>
> ✓ Completely Ad-free
>
> ✓ Minimal data usage and battery consumption
>
> ** Resizing widgets is supported from Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich)
> onwards

#### Download

[image]

#### Platform

The app is written for devices runnign Android. The minimal required system version is 2.2 (Froyo).

### Contact

Created by Paweł Kwieciński (yeah, thats me)

**pawel@kwiecinski.me**

Icon designed by Sebastian Pożoga

**sebastian@pozoga.eu**

Answer (score 2):

A little heads-up: Google play returns

> "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server."

Comment: And the app can't be found in the [Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=StackFlair).